# How to overload operators with Boost.Python

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, boost-python, compiler-errors

I am trying to overload operators of a C++ class using Boost.Python.

According to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_operators_special_functions), I am doing it the right way... but I have a bunch of compiler errors.

Here is a simple example I made trying to pinpoint the problem:

```
#include "boost/python.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

class number
{
public:
    number(int i) : m_Number(i) { }
    number operator+(int i) { return number(m_Number + i); }
private:
    int m_Number;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    class_<number>("number", init<int>())
        .def(self() + int());
}
```

Here are the compiler errors:

```
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments    c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\boostpythontest\boostpythontest\test.cpp   16  BoostPythonTest
Error   2   error C2780: 'boost::python::class_<W> &boost::python::class_<W>::def(const char *,Fn,const A1 &,const A2 &,const A3 &)' : expects 5 arguments - 1 provided c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\boostpythontest\boostpythontest\test.cpp   16  BoostPythonTest
Error   3   error C2780: 'boost::python::class_<W> &boost::python::class_<W>::def(const char *,Fn,const A1 &,const A2 &)' : expects 4 arguments - 1 provided    c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\boostpythontest\boostpythontest\test.cpp   16  BoostPythonTest
Error   4   error C2780: 'boost::python::class_<W> &boost::python::class_<W>::def(const char *,A1,const A2 &)' : expects 3 arguments - 1 provided   c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\boostpythontest\boostpythontest\test.cpp   16  BoostPythonTest
Error   5   error C2780: 'boost::python::class_<W> &boost::python::class_<W>::def(const char *,F)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided   c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\boostpythontest\boostpythontest\test.cpp   16  BoostPythonTest
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used boost.python, but your errors look like there are some incompatible arguments when some template magic tries to bind something to something else.

So I looked at the link you provided, and found one major difference:

```
class_<X>("X")
    .def(self + int())
```

vs yours

```
class_<number>("number", init<int>())
    .def(self() + int());
```

I guess, `self` and `self()` could do that.